# Can the blockchain's transactions be encrypted?

Tags: blockchain

Is it possible to implement ethereum/bitcoin while its transactions are encrypted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ethereum you can not encrypt transactions in general, because it would make the validation by the network impossible.

You could encrypt specific fields/data within a contract, however, it would basically reduce your smart contracts to an expensive encrypted storage.

Moreover, using something like zero knowledge proofs, you can let the network validate the transaction while keeping the data private.

Finally, in theory there are schemas where calculations/validations can be performed on encrypted data (-> homomorphic encryption), however, I am not aware of an efficient and generalised execution environment for this.